# Do I have to be proficient with an Implement to get its properties?

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items, proficiency

I'm trying to get low-light vision with any magic item that is not a Head slot item. I found *Totem of the Night* (Adventurer's Vault 2 pg.46).

> **Property:** You gain low-light vision. If you already have low-light vision, you instead gain darkvision.

I'm not proficient with Totems though, and I'm ridiculously feat starved as it is. If I pick up the Totem, do I get low-light vision?

Answer (score 3):

**You do indeed need proficiency in the implement to gain it's magical effects.**

The general rules for non-magic implements can be found on page 272 of the *Rules Compendium:*

> ### Implements - Proficiency
>
> Unlike weapons, an implement doesn't grant a proficiency bonus. Instead, an adventurer must have proficiency with an implement to use it at all. In the hands of a nonproficient user, an implement - magical or nonmagical - is effectively a bauble.

Which then continues into *magic implements* on page 283 of the *RC:*

> Because an adventurer must have proficiency with an implement to use it, an adventurer cannot gain an implement's enchantment bonus or benefit from any of the implement's other characteristics (such as properties, powers, and critical hit effects) unless he or she has proficiency with the implement.

Since the low-light vision is a **property** of the *Totem of the Night*, you wouldn't gain it's effect unless you have proficiency with totems.